# Android system loadlibary error for cross compiled libxml

Tags: android, android-ndk, libxml2

I have cross compiled libxml2-2.90 for android by changing the CC, CFALGS LDFLAGS with android ndk . and run the config and make , it compiled successfully .

Then I wrote simple libxml2 based example in native c , and wrote Android.mk file which includes the above libs and includes to compile the shared library .

1.I used ndk-build script and  successfully  compiled the native libxml application

1. I placed these two libs in android project /libs/armeabi
2. Then I loaded these two library in the android java application code

   System.loadLibrary("xml2"); //libxml2.so.2.9.0

   System.loadLibrary("samplexml2"); //libsamplexml2.so

but when I run my application I got the below run time error for android app .

Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/xmlsample/XmlParse;

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:    37 could not load needed library **'libxml2.so.2'** for 'libsamplexml2.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libxml2.so.2' not found)

Pls help how to properly link the xml2 lib ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When cross-compiling for android you must disable setting soname for library. If you use automake, replace -version-info SOME:VERSION:NUMBER to -avoid-version, and then reconfigure and recompile your library(libxml) and all dependencies (libsamplexml).

Comment: Since it is big makefile can you tell how to remove the version in config or makefile , I could change and generate only  libxml2.so.0.0.0 ..

Comment: I assume you use standalone toolchain for android to build your libraries. Edit Makefile.am and find string `-version-info @LIBXML_VERSION_INFO@`, replace this string to  `-avoid-version` then start `sh autogen.sh`, and then reconfigure. After compiling you can check soname `arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -p libxml.so | grep SONAME`.